# Azure alerts for a deleted azure container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-alerts

I am aware that we can configure an azure alert for 'Delete Storage Account'.
Is it also possible to configure an azure alert for 'Delete Azure Container'?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 0507:**

You should create a **Log Analytics workspace**. Please follow the steps below:

1.In azure portal -> nav to your storage account -> Activity log, then click **Logs** button:

[image]

2.In the new page, click **Add** button:

[image]

3.In the new page, click **Select a workspace** :

[image]

4.In the new page, click **Create New Workspace** :

[image]

5.Then follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace#create-a-workspace) to create a workspace. After the workspace is ready, you can do some operations like delete a blob container. And then nav to the **Log Analytics workspace** -> Logs, and run the command(Note: it may take a few minutes to wait for the logs to be generated):

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

Yes, it's possible.

In azure portal -> nav to Monitor -> Logs, then write the following query:

```
AzureActivity 
| where OperationName contains "Delete blob container"
```

Then click "New alert rule", and in the alert page, complete other settings.

[image]

Comment: In my New Query page, "Save" and "New alert rule" buttons have been disabled. I referenced the link of https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30719 but still cannot figure out.

Comment: @Learner, can you please attach a screenshot in your post? So I can try to figure out the root cause.

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: @Learner, the screenshot is very helpful. I have updated my answer, you should create a Log Analytics workspace. Please refer to the updated section for more details.